# Whats the best way to handle a SQL query on a Date (no time)?

Tags: sql, sql-server, datetime, ado.net

We have date columns in our database that are just a day - like birth date. However, SQL Server stores them as a date & time and the time in the records has various values (no idea how it ended up that way).

The problem is people will run a query for all `birthdates <= {some date}` and the ones that are equal aren't returned because a `DateTime` (using ADO.NET) set to a given date has a time of midnight.

I understand what's going on. The question is how best to handle this. We could force in a time of 23:23:59.999999999 to the date but that feels like it would have problems.

What's the standard best practice for handling this?

Comment: Which **version** of SQL Server? If you're on 2008 or newer, you can always use `CAST(yourcolumn AS DATE)` to get rid of any time portion. You could even think about created extra **computed, persisted** columns that just encapsulate that `CAST` - so you'd have a separate, **date-only** column in your relevant tables

Comment: Open-ended date range, always. `DateColumn >= <first day of range> AND DateColumn < <day *after* last day of range>;` Please see https://sqlblog.org/2011/10/19/what-do-between-and-the-devil-have-in-common, https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/16/bad-habits-to-kick-mis-handling-date-range-queries, http://www.sqlperformance.com/2012/09/t-sql-queries/what-is-the-most-efficient-way-to-trim-time-from-datetime and http://www.sqlperformance.com/2012/10/t-sql-queries/trim-time

Comment: I think the better answer is to just change the `datetime` column to `date`. Or at the very least, zero out their time, and fix whatever broken code is including time in the first place.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Simply add 1 day to {some_date} and use a less than comparison. Just make sure it's the next day at 12am...

Comment: +1 agreed 100%. Any other tricks are prone to erros caused by conversion to the wrong type (e.g. 23:59:997 rounds up if the data type is SMALLDATETIME).

Comment: yup, and that whole 3ms as the smallest unit of time should throw red flags to anyone trying to get to the last ms of a day.

Comment: @dotjoe: that 3ms of course only applies to `DATETIME` - SQL Server 2008 `DATETIME2`, `DATETIMEOFFSET` and `TIME` do **NOT** have that limitation ....

Comment: @marc_s good to know, I'm yet to use anything besides datetime

Comment: I like this best because the user is explicitly working with the data as is. And it does not require any change to the database (which is a limit for our case).

Answer (score 3):

If you need to query this frequently, I would probably add a computed, persisted column that casts your `DATETIME` to just a `DATE` (assuming you're on SQL Server **2008** or newer):

```
ALTER TABLE dbo.YourTableName
ADD JustDay AS CAST(YourDateTimeColumn AS DATE) PERSISTED
```

That way, you can now query on `JustDay` and it's just a `DATE` - no time portion involved. Since it's computed, there's no need to update it constantly; SQL Server will do this automagically for you. And since it's persisted, it's part of the table's on-disk structure and just as fast as a query on any other column - and it can even be indexed, if needed.

It's a classic *space - vs - speed* tradeoff - since you're now storing the date-only portion of all your birthdays, too, you're on-disk structure will be larger; on the other hand, since you have a nice, date-only column that can be indexed, you have a great way to speed up searches.

Comment: Well `CONVERT(DATE, column)` is actually a sargable expression (the only such expression I know of), so I would argue that the computed column is not necessary.

Answer (score 1):

You say

> The problem is people will run a query for all birthdates <= {some
>   date}

You could leave it as is and make sure people get rid of the time by using something like the following in their `WHERE` clauses:

```
CONVERT(DATETIME,CONVERT(CHAR(8),birthdates,112))<= {some date}
```

..or in later versions of SQL-Server:

```
CONVERT(DATE,birthdates)<= {some date}
```

But this is a workaround and best to take the other advice and get rid of the time in the actual target data.

Answer (score 0):

One more option is:

```
DATEDIFF(d, birthdates, {some date}) <= 0
```

Comment: Not sargable = poor advice.

Comment: Well I must agree on that.